# Weird touch/click events stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch, dom-events

I'm handling 5 events on a button - `touchstart`, `touchend`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` (assume that I'm creating something simillar to a "ripple button"). For `touchstart / mousedown` I'm using unified handler as well as for `touchend / mouseup` When there is no touch input then everything is fine. But when the touch event is present, the stack of events became too weird:

1. If you clicking (read as "touching") the button quick, then the stack is: `touchstart` -> `touchend` -> `mousedown` -> `mouseup` -> `click`, so the unified handlers are firing twice (as expected), but the click event is firing, that is fine.
2. If you tap'n'hold and then release (without a pixel movement), then the stack is: `touchstart` -> `touchend` (ok). But, as you see, there is no click event (when de-facto there was a click).

The code snipped below is fully reproducing this bug (as-designed behaviour? maybe I don't understand something?). Note that I did not `preventDefault`ed or `stopPropagation`ed anything, all events are fully saved their bubbling and default behaviour.

Actually, the second behaviour is more unwanted, because the first one is working in according to the spec (basically, it was expected as it was described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent)).

Any ideas how to fix this (I mean, how to return the `click` event for the second behaviour)?

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  handlePressStart = (event) => {
    if (event.targetTouches) {
      console.log("touchstart")
    } else {
      console.log("mousedown")
    }
  }
  
  handlePressEnd = (event) => {
    console.log("doesn't matter which event, pressend")
  }
  
  handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log("click")
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onTouchStart={this.handlePressStart}
        onMouseDown={this.handlePressStart}
        onTouchEnd={this.handlePressEnd}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        My awesome button
      </button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("kappa"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="kappa"></div>
```

Comment: But there wasn't any 'click' events. It just works as it should. Click event dispatches when you `click` on the object - make mouseDown and mouseUp with short duration.

Comment: @AlexShtromberg not exactly. With mouse pointer click event triggers when you `mousedown` and `mouseup` on a particular element. It doesn't matter, how long did you press a mouse button, it only matters on which element it was started and ended.